# GeoTools GML parser sorted features collection

Tags: geotools, gml

I am using the following code to parse GML file in java:

```
File gmlFile = new File("path/to/gml/file");    
InputStream gmlInStream = new FileInputStream(gmlFile);
GML gml = new GML(Version.WFS1_0);
SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = gml.decodeFeatureCollection(gmlInStream);
SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = featureCollection.features();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       SimpleFeature feature = iterator.next();
       //Do something with the feature
}
iterator.close();
```

I need to have the returned features collection be sorted by a specific feature's attribute. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a [`SortBy`](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/opengis/filter/sort/SortBy.html) to your [`Query`](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/data/Query.html) object.

So for example the following code sorts the US States dataset by population (`PERSONS`):

```
    URL u = TestData.url("shapes/statepop.shp");
    FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(u);
    SimpleFeatureType schema = store.getSchema();
    Query query = new Query(schema.getTypeName(), Filter.INCLUDE, 
         new String[] { "STATE_NAME", "PERSONS", "WORKERS" });
    FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
    query.setSortBy(new SortBy[] { ff.sort("PERSONS", SortOrder.ASCENDING) });
    SimpleFeatureCollection features = store.getFeatureSource().getFeatures(query);
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = features.features()) {
      while (itr.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature feature = itr.next();
        System.out.println(feature.getAttribute("STATE_NAME") + "\t" + feature.getAttribute("PERSONS"));
      }
    }
```

Or if, as in your case, you have a `FeatureCollection` and no `FeatureSource` you can wrap them using the `DataUtilities` class:

```
File gmlFile = new File("/home/ian/Downloads/states.xml");
InputStream gmlInStream = new FileInputStream(gmlFile);
GML gml = new GML(Version.WFS1_0);
features = gml.decodeFeatureCollection(gmlInStream);
query = new Query();
query.setSortBy(new SortBy[] { ff.sort("name", SortOrder.DESCENDING) });
features = DataUtilities.source(features).getFeatures(query);
try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = features.features()) {
  while (itr.hasNext()) {
    SimpleFeature feature = itr.next();
    System.out.println(feature.getAttribute("name") + "\t" + feature.getAttribute("pop_2018"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not able to create a Datastore from the GML file, I tried the following but it return null. FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(gmlFile.toURL());

Comment: That is just set up in my example, you need the 2nd way of creating the featureCollection I show followed by the iterator loop

Comment: But your 2nd way needs a query object, and the query object needs a schema object, and the schema object needs a DataStore :). So how can I create a DataStore from a GML file? or if you have any other solution?

Comment: Use `features.getSchema()` to get the schema of your feature collection to create the Query with

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ian Turton, it works perfectly.